# How can I print table in horizontal in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

I want to print a database table in horizontal order. Can I use `CASE` or some thing else and how?

```
ID   NAME
--   ----
101  abc
102  xyz
103  pqr
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
101 abc 102 xyz 103 pqr
```

Comment: You'll have to give more information (table structure, example data, which value decides into which column the information should go) to get sensible answers - google for SQL Pivot table to get Some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here replace by your  table and column name and use this SQL:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(100);
SELECT @str = COALESCE(@str + ' ', '') + column_name FROM table_name
SELECT @str
```

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @str VARCHAR(100); 
SELECT @str = COALESCE(@str + ' ', '') + convert(varchar,ID) + '  ' + NAME FROM TableName
SELECT @str

Answer (score 0):

First of all it does not make sense that you list all the platforms as tags - you can only use one at a time

Is this a real question?  Maybe you just learning about sql and wondering if there is a "easy" way to do this?  The answer is no.

SQL is not the best way to do this -- if you are calling SQL from another environment that language is better suited for formatting printout.  c, c++, C#, PHP, Python etc will all let you take db data and stream it to an output without newlines.

I most use cases this is the best way to solve the problem.

HOWEVER, if you can give more information about what you are actually trying to do there may be a way to solve the problem well in SQL.  Given your question the answer is no, use the calling language to format the print out this way.

Comment: hello , when i went 4 one interviw that time i faced this question.

Comment: ok, then I expect the question contained more information.  Like more detail on the output.